# tidb cannot fuzzy query with like '_' for double byte character?

Tags: sql, tidb

In my program, I want to lookup "测试" with

```sql
select * from test where name like '测_';
```

After my test, I found that MySQL can, but tidb can't?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine for me. What character set is your table, column and connection? What TiDB version are you using?

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (id char(2) character set utf8mb4 primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('测试'),('测x');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id LIKE '测_';
+--------+
| id     |
+--------+
| 测x    |
| 测试   |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.11 sec)

mysql> SELECT tidb_version();
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tidb_version()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Release Version: v5.4.0
Edition: Community
Git Commit Hash: 55f3b24c1c9f506bd652ef1d162283541e428872
Git Branch: heads/refs/tags/v5.4.0
UTC Build Time: 2022-01-25 08:39:26
GoVersion: go1.16.4
Race Enabled: false
TiKV Min Version: v3.0.0-60965b006877ca7234adaced7890d7b029ed1306
Check Table Before Drop: false |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)
```